# How to add a deeply nested object to a deeply nested Array in a React Reducer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, use-reducer

I have following React State:

```
state: {
   objectOne: {
      arrayOne: [
         {
            arrayTwo: [
                {
                   value: 'some value'
                }
            ]         
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am using React useContext and the useReducer hooks.
What I want to do is to add an object to arrayTwo.

**What I have tried so far:**

I call a dispatch function with the type of "ADD_NEW_OBJECT" and the payload is an object with some key value pairs in it.

```
    dispatchFunction({
       type: 'ADD_NEW_OBJECT', 
       payload: {
          value: {
             a: 'this is the ',
             b: 'object I want to add',
          }
          arrayOneIndex: 0, 
          arrayTwoIndex: 0
       }
    });
```

**This is my useReducer case-Statement:**

```
case 'ADD_NEW_OBJECT':
            return {
                ...state,
                objectOne: {
                    ...state.objectOne,
                    arrayOne: [
                        ...state.objectOne.arrayOne,
                        {
                            ...state.objectOne.arrayOne[payload.arrayOneIndex],
                            arrayTwo: [
                                ...state.objectOne.arrayOne[payload.arrayOneIndex].arrayTwo,
                                payload.value
                            ]
                        },
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) is a great library for simplifying this code. It generates a deep clone of the object passed to it and then you can mutate the clone.

```
import produce from "immer";

const reducer = produce((draft, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_NEW_OBJECT:
      draft.objectOne.arrayOne[action.payload.arrayOneIndex][
        action.payload.arrayTwoIndex
      ].push(value);
      return draft;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer. I have tried it but I get a TypeError as follows:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: It already fails with draft.objectOne.arrayOne as he can't find it and returns undefined.

Comment: are you sure that the array actually exists there?

Comment: Yes of course. The structure of the state is like above.